# How to stretch the length of fraction bar?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I want to stretch the length of every fraction bar a bit. I know I can define a new command like this:

```
\newcommand\newfrac[2]{\frac{\,#1\,}{\,#2\,}}
```

However, I want to set the longer-style fraction as default, so I can keep writing `$\frac{}{}$` and get what I want.

I know that there are some commands related to this in the Appendix G in the [TeXBook](http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/texbook.pdf). However, this is hard for me to figure out how to. Need your help.

PS: I'm using 12pt, book class and `mtpro2` math font with XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're using `amsmath`, where the definition

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\frac}[2]{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\@@over#2}}
```

is found, just modify it; in your preamble add

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\frac}[2]{{\begingroup\,#1\,\endgroup\@@over\,#2\,}}
\makeatother
```

In math mode `\,` means `\mskip\thinmuskip`, so its value depends on the quad in the current math symbol font (and scales automatically with it).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\let` to copy the original command and than you can redefine it:

```
\let \originalfrac=\frac
\renewcommand{\frac}[2]{\originalfrac{\,#1\,}{\,#2\,}}
```

**EDIT:** better:

```
\let \originalfrac=\frac
\DeclareRobustCommand{\myfrac}[2]{\originalfrac{\,#1\,}{\,#2\,}} 
\let \frac=\myfrac
```

This differs from the first approach in 2 ways:

- It defines a newcommand instead of renewing an existing one. Replacing the command happens with `\let` instead of with `\renewcommand`.
  Regarding why this is better, see the example below.
- It makes the new command robust. As pointed out by Marco Daniel a simple `\newcommand` instead of `\DeclareRobustCommand` would cause double spacing in the table of contents if using this command in a section title.

With the first approach you will run into trouble when dealing with commands which do not do the job itself but call another command which does it for them, like for example commands with an optional parameter or with a starred version.
Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\test}[1][world]{hello #1}
    \show\test
    \expandafter\show\csname\string\test\endcsname

\let \originaltest=\test
\renewcommand{\test}[1][world]{\originaltest[\emph{#1}]}
    \show\test
    \show\originaltest
    \expandafter\show\csname\string\test\endcsname

\begin{document}
\ifx \test \originaltest
    true
\else
    false
\fi
\end{document}
```

Here, the definition of `\test` does not change because (leaving all of the protection stuff aside) it does nothing more than handling the optional parameter (which is the same in this example).
The really interesting stuff, that you intended to copy, however, was saved in another command called `\\test` and was overridden by `\renewcommand`.

If you would try to expand `\test` now you would run into an infinite loop: `\test` would somehow expand to `\\test` which would expand to `\originaltest[\emph{#1}]` which would somehow expand to `\\test` again and so on.

Comment: By the way, will the actual length of `\,` differ in the different environment(e.g. in `\large` or in `\tiny`)? I'm afraid that the length of `\,` is too 'absolute', not flexible. But I just came up with this command in my mind, so I wonder if there are better one. :)

Comment: Be careful with this solution. `amsmath` makes `\frac`robust. So you can't use `\let`. I recommend the package `letltxmacro`: `\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\originalfrac\frac
\DeclareRobustCommand\frac[2]{\originalfrac{\,#1\,}{\,#2\,}} `

Comment: @MarcoDaniel  I'm using `amsmath`, but I can write the command `\let \originalfrac=\frac` and pass the compiler. Why?

Comment: @Eric `\show\,` shows that `\,` is defined as `\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}` (with amsmath loaded). Sounds like it does depend on the font size.

Comment: @jakun: In most cases it will work. Here an example which shows the error: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\let \originalfrac=\frac
%renewcommand{\frac}[2]{\originalfrac{\,#1\,}{\,#2\,}}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\originalfrac\frac
\DeclareRobustCommand\frac[2]{\originalfrac{\,#1\,}{\,#2\,}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c}$}
\end{document}
`

Comment: Have a look in the table of contents. It look weird. Try both and have a look at the aux-file.